# Does making position fixed reduce document height?

Tags: html, css

I am really confused with this. Here I've got a **div** whose **position** should be **fixed** after **certain scroll**. **Before position** of that div is **absolute**. I tried it and found that for one of my screens fixing position is really making document less while on other screen it is not.

What I want to know is which of them is a  bug? Does **fixing position** of element **decreases** document **height**?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a fixed positioning for an element, it is removed from the "normal layout flow". The height of your document is determined by positioning of all the elements in the page and **thus, all changes to positioning affect document height**.

Fixed and absolute positioning are explained in detail in the CSS Visual formatting model spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

Regarding absolute positioning (from the spec):

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with
>   respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow
>   entirely (it has no impact on later siblings).

Pretty much the same applies for fixed positioning (Ibid.):

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only
>   difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is
>   established by the viewport.

Comment: Yeah i know that, it is perfect behaviour, but as i told you in one of my screens I found it is not happening, so I thought of asking it, anyways i know you are right, there is some problem with second screen.

Comment: Oh I see. If you want to have specific  tips, please provide some markup/code!